# How to calculate RGB mean values for each individual ROI if there are multiple ROIs in single image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have an image with 3 channels in RGB format, containing many buildings as regions of interest. The background of the image is completely black (zero pixels). I tried to calculate its color features for each individual ROI, and saving them in CSV file, but my code is taking only single RGB value as mean for each channel, as I need to save R, G, B, and RGB mean values of each single ROI in CSV file. Any guidance would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4IXb.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from skimage import io

image = io.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/277.png")

current_roi = 1
start_pixel = None
roi_mean_values = []

for y in range(image.shape[0]):
for x in range(image.shape[1]):

pixel_value = image[y, x]

     if np.any(pixel_value > 0):  
           if start_pixel is None:
                 start_pixel = (x, y)
           elif start_pixel is not None:
               end_pixel = (x - 1, y)  # End of the current ROI
               roi = image[start_pixel[1]:end_pixel[1] + 1, start_pixel[0]:end_pixel[0] + 1]
    
               mean_rgb = np.mean(roi, axis=(0, 1))
               roi_mean_values.append({'ROI': current_roi,
                                    'Mean_R': mean_rgb[0],
                                    'Mean_G': mean_rgb[1],
                                    'Mean_B': mean_rgb[2]})
    
              current_roi += 1
              start_pixel = None

roi_mean_df = pd.DataFrame(roi_mean_values)

roi_mean_df.to_csv("roi_mean_values.csv", index=False)

print("RGB mean values for individual buildings (ROIs) saved to 'roi_mean_values.csv'.")
```

Comment: You need to iterate over your ROIs, not over the pixels. So, loop over each of your ROIs in turn. For each one, make a mask that is white within that ROI and black everywhere else. Mask the entire image with that and calculate your statistics. Then go to next ROI.

Comment: So the ROIs are the connected components in the image?

Comment: No, all ROIs are not connected to each other. These are the buildings from remote sensing image and the background is completely black (zero pixels) so to calculate the color features of each single ROI and then save in CSV.

Comment: Please share a representative image with some ROIs.

Comment: I agree with Mark, you should be iterating over ROIs then computing the mean of the pixels within each ROI, based on your requirements as described above. In your current snippet I see you're loading a png file but I don't see where this ROI data is loaded/created. You should post that along with a test image. (The `/content/drive/MyDrive` path hints you may be using a Colab notebook. Maybe the rest of your notebook contains the part where these ROIs are created or loaded ?)

Comment: Yes George, I'm on colab notebook. The code is saving values for each channel instead of each ROI. I agree that I have to iterate over the ROIs, also I shared my image that I am working on above at the description part.

Comment: Have you printed out your ROI coordinates?  I'm guessing they're not what you think they are.

Comment: So, yes, the ROIs are the connected components in the image. —— When you reply to a comment, please add `@` in front of the name you’re replying to, that way the person gets notified. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) under “Replying in comments”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Noted, and Thank you so much for the guidance as well as your code amendment

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the ROIs are given by the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) of the input image. Each connected component is an ROI.

You can solve this problem without iterating over ROIs, which can get quite expensive if there are many. This code does explicitly iterate over pixels though, which is slow in Python. Maybe, iterating over ROIs and using compiled functions to process all pixels yields faster Python code, even though much more work is actually being done. But written in a compiled language, this algorithm is the most efficient one you can write.

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage

image = skimage.io.imread("/Users/cris/Downloads/G4IXb.png")
n_channels = image.shape[2]

# Find binary image separating background and objects
mask = np.any(image > 0, axis=2)

# Label this mask image, each ROI gets a unique label
lab, n_labs = skimage.measure.label(mask, return_num=True)

# Create arrays where we'll collect the information
sum = np.zeros((n_labs + 1, n_channels))
number = np.zeros(n_labs + 1)

# Loop over all pixels.
for ii in range(image.shape[0]):
    for jj in range(image.shape[1]):
        # For each pixel, look at the label, and add information to
        # the arrays for that label.
        index = lab[ii, jj]
        sum[index, :] += image[ii, jj, :]
        number[index] += 1

# We're done. The mean color is the sum divided by the number of pixels.
mean_colors = sum / number[:, None]
```

Let's see what the mean colors look like:

```py
# Paint an image with the mean colors
mean_colors = np.round(mean_colors).astype(np.uint8)
out = np.empty_like(image)
for ii in range(image.shape[0]):
    for jj in range(image.shape[1]):
        out[ii, jj] = mean_colors[lab[ii, jj]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

[image: output of code above]

Of course, since we're using skimage, we might as well use [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops), and get the `intensity_mean` property:

```py
props = skimage.measure.regionprops(lab, image)
cols = np.zeros((n_labs + 1, n_channels))
for p in props:
    cols[p.label, :] = p.intensity_mean
```